# Ionic 2 ScreenOrientation Plugin Changes

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins, screen-orientation

I need your help with this: Two months ago, my Ionic 2 app was working right, using the ScreenOrientation cordova plugin, with this code:

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', ()=>{
  console.info('DEVICE ORIENTATION CHANGED!');
  console.debug(ScreenOrientation.orientation);
  if(ScreenOrientation.orientation.type.indexOf('landscape') !== -1){
    this.screenOrientationIsPortrait = false;
  } else if(ScreenOrientation.orientation.type.indexOf('portrait') !== -1){
    this.screenOrientationIsPortrait = true;
  }
});
```

In a new laptop, I installed the most recent Ionic 2 version, and the most recent version of the cordova ScreenOrientation plugin, and with the same app code, and I´m getting this error in Compile time:

> Property 'type' does not exist on type 'string'.

I tried using the examples in the github repository of the ScreenOrientation plugin:

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', ()=>{
  console.info('DEVICE ORIENTATION CHANGED!');
  console.debug(ScreenOrientation.orientation);
  if(screen.orientation.type.indexOf('landscape') !== -1){
    this.screenOrientationIsPortrait = false;
  } else if(screen.orientation.type.indexOf('portrait') !== -1){
    this.screenOrientationIsPortrait = true;
  }
});
```

but with that code, I´m getting this error also in Compile Time:

> Property 'orientation' does not exist on type 'Screen'

Both, Ionic 2 and the ScreenOrientation Plugin have been updated recently. Based on my research, It appears a TypeScript error, not an updating versions conflict.

How can I know what is wrong? How can I debug to find the reason of this new errors?  Any Ideas? Thanks in advance, I appreciate your help.

Github repo examples: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

Ionic 2 Examples: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/screen-orientation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually detect screen orientation change without adding the plugin too. Use property orientation of type window.

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', () => {
      console.info('DEVICE ORIENTATION CHANGED!');
      console.debug(ScreenOrientation.orientation);
      switch (window.orientation) {
        case -90:
        case 90:
              console.log("Landscape orientation");
              this.screenOrientationIsPortrait = true;
              break;
        case 0:
             console.log("Landscape orientation");
              this.screenOrientationIsPortrait = false;
             break;
      }      
    });
```

Comment: Thaks for your help, I´m using your solution and it works fine. But I didn´t find the reason of the plugin and typeScript errors. Regards.